# What would be a good Minizinc model for redistricting?

Tags: minizinc

I'm looking into political redistricting, and wonder what would be the best model

A sample problem would be:
7000 census tracts, each with coordinates and population,
to be assigned to 53 districts.

constraint: populations of all districts to be within 1%

maximize: "compactness" of districts (ie: minimize gerrymandering)

For a simple measure of compactness I might use mean/median of distances from the centroid.

This seems to be a fairly straightforward clustering problem with constraints,
but in the tutorial I see no mention of clustering problems.

The knapsack model of the tutorial wouldn't seem to accommodate the compactness requirement.

What would be the best model compatible with Minizinc?

Comment: What have you done so far? Please show the code so we might help you finetuning. Also, can you describe in more detail what political redistricting means?

Comment: The question also seems to be how you would define compactness. This will have a big influence on the model.

Comment: Hakank: I don't have minizinc code yet. I'm trying to select the model. The closest I see so far would be the knapsack model

Comment: Dekker: I was hoping to just have a 'compactness' subroutine the optimizer could call, so I wouldn't have to incorporate it into the model. The metric I'm favoring in mean/median of distances from the centroid.